# How to use node modules dependencies common for different projects using webpack and react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

can someone help me out, below is my issue.

I have 5 projects with different setups (each setup contains its own node modules)

there are some common node modules across the 5 projects, i want to use them globally how can I do that?

what I have tried is:
created vendor file in all projects with common dependencies and used one form it but it is not working.

for example projectA vendor is working with only projectA but not working remaining projects b,c,d and E, this is same for all other projects

can someone help me please

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/681

Comment: yes, but it is in local, but I want to use common node modules across the different projects in production